# SQL insert into database using PHP

Tags: php, sql, post, sql-insert

Hey guys I'm just practising inserting data into my database for the first time and i've got a few issues with my code.

So what my code does is that it takes information from a form and simply inserts it into the database I have connected to. I'm getting 2 types errors, one is an undefined index at my POSTS and I'm also getting a SQL syntax error. I've tried looking around with no such luck in helping me fix the problem.

(yea I forgot to add the messages when I posted) Edit:

Undefined index: customerid on line 57

Problem with queryYou have an error in your SQL syntax;  '', '', '', '', '', '')' at line 2

Any advice would be helpful:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title>Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Customer Information Collection <br /></h1>
<form method="post" action="task12.php" id="custinfo" >
   <table>
   <tr>
        <td><label for="customerid">Customer ID (integer value): </label></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="customerid" name="customerid" size=11/></td>
    </tr>
   <tr>
        <td><label for="customerfname">Customer First Name: </label></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="customerfname" name="customerfname" size=50/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label for="customerlname">Customer Last Name: </label></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="customerlname" name="customerlname" size=50/></td>
    </tr>
   <tr>
        <td><label for="customeraddress">Customer Address: </label></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="customeraddress" name="customeraddress" size=65/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label for="suburb"> Suburb: </label></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="suburb" name="suburb"/></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td> State: </td>
   <td> <select name="state" id="state">
        <option value="--">--</option>
        <option value="ACT">ACT</option>
        <option value="NSW">NSW</option>
        <option value="NT">NT</option>
        <option value="QLD">QLD</option>
        <option value="SA">SA</option>
        <option value="TAS">TAS</option>
        <option value="VIC">VIC</option>
         <option value="WA">WA</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><label for="postcode"> Post Code (default "2000"): </label></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="postcode" name="postcode" value="2000" size=4/></td>
   </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/> </td>
    <td> <input type="reset" value="Clear" /> </td>
  </tr>
     </table>
  </form>
<?php 
$customeridstr = $_POST['customerid']; 
$customerfnamestr = $_POST['customerfname']; 
$customerlnamestr = $_POST['customerlname']; 
$customeraddressstr = $_POST['customeraddress'];  
$suburbstr = $_POST['suburb'];  
$statestr = $_POST['state']; 
$postcodestr = $_POST['postcode'];  
?>
<?php 
$conn = mysql_connect("xxxxx", "xxxxx", "xxxxxx");
mysql_select_db("xxxxxxx", $conn)
or die ('Database not found ' . mysql_error() );
$sql = "INSERT INTO Customer (customerID, firstName, lastName, Address, suburb, state, postcode)
VALUES ( '$customeridstr', '$customerfnamestr’, '$customerlnamestr', '$customeraddressstr', '$suburbstr', '$statestr', '$postcodestr');";
$rs = mysql_query($sql, $conn)
or die ('Problem with query' . mysql_error());  
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post the SQL-error?

Comment: Add the errors. Please do not make us read trought your code line by line to find a undefined index... Learn what the error messages mean. They are there for a reason.

Comment: Sorry I was in the middle of grabbing them when you posted that as I forgot to add them when I was posting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['customerid'])){
   $customeridstr = $_POST['customerid']; 
   $customerfnamestr = $_POST['customerfname']; 
   $customerlnamestr = $_POST['customerlname']; 
   $customeraddressstr = $_POST['customeraddress'];  
   $suburbstr = $_POST['suburb'];  
   $statestr = $_POST['state']; 
   $postcodestr = $_POST['postcode'];  

   $conn = mysql_connect("xxxxx", "xxxxx", "xxxxxx");
   mysql_select_db("xxxxxxx", $conn) or die ('Database not found ' . mysql_error() );
   $sql = "INSERT INTO Customer (customerID, firstName, lastName, Address, suburb, state, postcode) VALUES ( '{$customeridstr}', '{$customerfnamestr}’, '{$customerlnamestr}', '{$customeraddressstr}', '{$suburbstr}', '{$statestr}', '{$postcodestr}');";
   $rs = mysql_query($sql, $conn);  
   if($rs){
       echo 'Records Inserted';
   }else{
       die ('Problem with query' . mysql_error());
   }
}else{
?>    

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title>Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Customer Information Collection <br /></h1>
<form method="post" action="" id="custinfo" >
   <table>
   <tr>
        <td><label for="customerid">Customer ID (integer value): </label></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="customerid" name="customerid" size=11/></td>
    </tr>
   <tr>
        <td><label for="customerfname">Customer First Name: </label></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="customerfname" name="customerfname" size=50/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label for="customerlname">Customer Last Name: </label></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="customerlname" name="customerlname" size=50/></td>
    </tr>
   <tr>
        <td><label for="customeraddress">Customer Address: </label></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="customeraddress" name="customeraddress" size=65/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label for="suburb"> Suburb: </label></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="suburb" name="suburb"/></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td> State: </td>
   <td> <select name="state" id="state">
        <option value="--">--</option>
        <option value="ACT">ACT</option>
        <option value="NSW">NSW</option>
        <option value="NT">NT</option>
        <option value="QLD">QLD</option>
        <option value="SA">SA</option>
        <option value="TAS">TAS</option>
        <option value="VIC">VIC</option>
         <option value="WA">WA</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><label for="postcode"> Post Code (default "2000"): </label></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="postcode" name="postcode" value="2000" size=4/></td>
   </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/> </td>
    <td> <input type="reset" value="Clear" /> </td>
  </tr>
     </table>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
}
?>
```

For now, try the above solution, this should work.

For further learning try these things:

- Using mysqli instead my mysql library, it is deprecated now. try sanitizing the data (data you are getting from $_POST or $_GET).
- Set a separate file for database connection and include it where it is needed but only one time in one php script/page.
- Its also not a good practice to post the values on the same page, post it on some other page which is just dealing with the submitted data.
- Also we just check one variable that is it set or not, and also that doesn't verifies that is it empty or not, so try checking every required variable and condition you want to check.

Cheers :)

Comment: The code posted is vulnerable to sql-injections. It is also not guaranteed that any(except the explicitly checked) of the post fields are set.

Comment: I read it, but I doubt that most will read further than they require to solve their problem. However that doesn't degrade your answer in any way

Comment: @Rangad: depends on the style of teaching .. i don't want to make it complex that a beginner can't learn from it :)

Comment: And I totally support that in many cases. SQL-Injections are however security relevant so I'd make a difference here. But I guess there is nothing to argue about, since we only differ in weighting